# How to get a Spring IoC Bean using JSFUnit on JSF 1.2

Tags: java, spring, jsf, junit, jsfunit

So my application runs on **JSF 1.2** and uses the **Spring Beans IOC** to inject classes into Backing Beans based on the Spring Context XML configuration.

I am using **JSFUnit** for testing, and I can navigate through pages and assert on my Backing Bean values, however I am unable yet to access any of the injected beans.

I know JSFUnit has been advertized to do white-box testing, but so far I could only do stuff similar to the in-container testing made with Arquilian.

Can anyone help me with accessing the Business Object I have (injected by Spring) once I open the page related to the Backing Bean ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, once you navigate to your page, you can call this method in your test case which simply returns the bean by *bean name*, it's so neat:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T findBean(String beanName) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return (T) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{"+beanName+"}", Object.class);
}
```

Now JSFUnit became much more useful !